# Laravel hasOne Not Updating on Key Change

Tags: php, database, laravel, relationship, has-one

I have an User which has an Avatar and an Armory. The User can only have one Avatar (at the moment) and the Armory can hold any number of Armor. This all works great. However, the Avatar needs to have a Head, Chest, Arms, etc so I created head_id, chest_id, etc on the avatar table. Basically those represent the current piece they are wearing in each position. The Armory is the pieces they can choose from.

So in my Avatar model I have:

```
public function head()
{
    return $this->hasOne('Armor', 'id', 'head_id')
}
```

Which works just fine and returns me the piece of armor. The issue becomes when I POST data and try to change that piece of armor. What I do is:

```
$this->head_id = $newHeadID;
```

Which does actually change head_id, but if I then do $this->head(), it still returns the old *head*. I've tried **$this->save()** and **$this->push()** in-between, but it still doesn't update it immediately. The only way that seems to work is to entirely "re-query" like such:

```
$head = Armor::where('id', $this->head_id)->first();
```

I'm pretty sure I'm missing something like not doing an update, refresh, etc. Any ideas?

Comment: How would it know the information of the new head to populate the relation with if you haven't re-queried?  The only way to do this would be to pass that information in the post as well.

Comment: I guess that's part of what I'm wondering though. Is there a way to "update"? The code happens in the Avatar model. So I change the head_id in there and then I need to *use* that new head in there as well. Seems weird to do $head = User::some_query when I'm already in the model and should be able to just call $this->head() (I can't because it still points to the old one). Maybe it just seems weird to me and that is the correct way to do it. Just figured I'd check.